# How to store an object in MongoDB that has a key that starts with $

Tags: mongodb

I want to save changes made to my document. The easiest way to do this is to store the actual changes made to a document. What I mean:

```
var changes = {
  $set: {
    text: 'Some text.'
  }
}

db.posts.update({
  _id: _id
}, changes)

db.changes.insert({
  postid: _id,
  changes: changes
})
```

However I'm getting the error (with good reason):

```
Error: key $set must not start with '$'
```

What's the easiest way to store changes?

Or perhaps I'm approaching the problem wrong and you have a better solution. I want users to be able to see a log of changes people make to any post or, in fact, anything. I'm not going to make a function for every time of change. Editing the text is just one of many ways to make changes to a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation within MongoDB. There are certain reserved characters one of them being `$` due to how querying must work. When using operators there would be ambiguity between the document in the collection and the document used for updating.

I would recommend stripping out the `$` symbols. I would instead use these words in place of the operators you are trying to use:

- CREATE
- SET
- DELETE

Comment: do I have to do this for every type of $ modifier, only the top ones, or what?

Comment: @JonathanOng No typically an audit log only really has these three operators and you just shove in the new value and the old value, things like `$inc` etc will go down as a SET. You will need to think of whether sub documents should show in object form on the audit log or whethe you wanna audit each field of them individually.

Comment: I decided to just store it as `JSON.stringify(changes)`. simple!

Answer (score 5):

Another option, with many reservations, is to store your change log as a json string. The content would not be as easily searched, of course, but you can retain the simplicity of storing your original data as a string and decoding the json on retrieval. If you are simply storing a change log, this approach might work.

db.changes.insert({
  postid: _id,
  changes: JSON.stringify(changes)
})