# How to store mongoDB selectors in mongoDB with Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to store mongoDB selectors in a mongoDB collection, in order to do dynamic data-analysis.
But when I try to store more complex selectors, including `$`-prefixed expressions, such as the following (ran from Meteor/JavaScript):

```
filterBy:
  foo:
    $ne: "bar"
```

I get this error:

```
key $ne must not start with '$'
```

Is there a *proper* way to store mongoDB selectors or do I have to build some logic to replace and reverse-replace all the `$` in the object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store an object in MongoDB that has a key that starts with $](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739793/how-to-store-an-object-in-mongodb-that-has-a-key-that-starts-with)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I flagged it now; there wording was too different for me to find it, but it's basically the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As mentioned above, the question has [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739793/how-to-store-an-object-in-mongodb-that-has-a-key-that-starts-with) for general purposes. I will outline here a Meteor-specific solution.*

Using [Meteor Collection Hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) I added an automatic conversion upon save:

```
FilterCollection.before.insert (userId, doc) ->
  if doc.filterBy?
    doc.filterBy = JSON.stringify doc.filterBy
```

And then I use a regular `transform` to convert it back:

```
FilterCollection = new Meteor.Collection "filters",
   transform: (document) ->
     if document.filterBy?
        document.filterBy = JSON.parse document.filterBy
```